# How can an object with an ID disapear?

Tags: apex, future

I have an error logging object that stores errors.  In most cases, when I call my method to create a new Error Log record, it properly creates and inserts the record.  When I call the error logging method from an @future method, it does not persist.

I have a `System.debug` statement before and after the Insert is called and the statement after the Insert shows that the object has an ID.  The `FutureHandler` debug logs end shortly after the Insert is confirmed and the object is not deleted.  When I look for the object by the ID (both in the Developer Console Query Editor and in the actual Salesforce UI), the record is nowhere to be found.

How can I stop these records from disappearing?

Comment: Some reasons why a record might seem to disappear: you have a rollback in your code somewhere, an unhandled exception is thrown in your transaction, or you are in a unit test context.

Comment: @greenstork The error method is being called within a Catch block.  I'll try calling it outside of the Catch.

Comment: It seems that throwing the exception after catching it and trying to save the new Error Log record caused a roll-back.  Since it is in a Future method, throwing the exception is not technically necessary so I have removed the final "throw".  Now the record saves properly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a relevant example to catch exception and save to the responding object. It should work.

Ref: https://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Exception_Handling

Logging in a custom object
If you get enough emails already, another option would be to use a future method to write a custom object that could catch the error details. Your try-catch would look something like this:

```
try{
     throw new MyException('something bad happened!');
} catch (MyException e){
     ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL,'my error msg');
     futureCreateErrorLog.createErrorRecord(e.getMessage());
}
Your future class would look something like this.
global class futureCreateErrorLog {
     @future
     public static void createErrorRecord(string exceptionMessage){
         myErrorObj__c newErrorRecord = new myErrorObj__c();
         newErrorRecord.details__c = exceptionMessage;
         Database.insert(newErrorRecord,false);
     }
}
```